# "trap 'killall $$ ; rm -f $folder2;exit ' 18 20 24

Tags: linux, shell, kill

What is wrong with this command?

```
$ trap 'killall $$ ; rm -f $folder2;exit ' 18 20 24
```

That command is in a `for` loop, and while that `for` is executing, if I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> I want it to stop the process and delete all the files that were created (inside `folder2`) and `folder2` itself.

But when i press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> in the terminal it stops but I can't do anything else afterwards, not even <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is not working.

Comment: If you have comments on an answer, either update the question, or comment here. Don't forget to ping the person your comment is supposed to reach. For instance, to ping me in a comment, you would use @JosephR

Comment: Signal numbers aren't portable (even different Linux architectures use different ones). Are you meaning to trap `SIGCONT`, `SIGTSTP`, and `SIGXCPU`? I suggest you use the names in your script—those are portable.

Comment: question also appears here http://stackoverflow.com/q/20125545/7552

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `killall` is expecting a pattern that would match a process name rather than its PID, while `$$` supplies the current process PID. You want to use `kill` instead.

Also, if you want to remove a directory along with all its contents, you need the `-r` switch to `rm`:

Finally, anything you do after you kill your process, won't take effect: move the `kill` to the end of the `trap` and remove the `exit` altogether:

```
trap 'rm -rf "$folder2";kill $$' 18 20 24
```

If you want to stop the `for` loop from working before removing `$folder2`, you can use `break`:

```
trap 'break;rm -rf "$folder2";kill $$' 18 20 24
```

Comment: OP's comment:
"i tried what you said but it's still not working . While the proces is active , if i press CTRL-Z the process stops (or suspends) but then nothing happens . i can't even get out of the command with ctrl+c."

Comment: thx it worked :)

Comment: @alex I'm glad I could help. If this answer helped you, please upvote it and mark it accepted so others browsing the forum know that this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Take the following script as an example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo bye; kill $$' SIGTSTP
sleep 30
```

Say you hit control-Z during the sleep. That'll send SIGTSTP to the process group, which will include sleep and bash. As explained in [William Pursell's answer to a similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12825003/27727) bash doesn't run the `trap` handler until after the running command (`sleep`) terminates. However, sleep will not terminate: it has suspended, because it also received SIGTSTP. And at this point, because it's stopped, it'll ignore control-C (SIGTERM), control-\ (SIGQUIT), etc. Nothing short of SIGKILL will bring it down.

So your `trap` won't run (unless you go ahead and kill -9 the sleep, then it'll immediately run).

In order to get around this, you'll need to [get your child processes to ignore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4515549/27727) or not be delivered the SIGTSTP, then handle killing them yourself. Or run them in the background, and `wait` for them:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo bye; kill $$' SIGTSTP
sleep 30 &
wait
```

Control-Z actually works as expected with that one.

Comment: @Patrick SIGSTOP != SIGTSTP. The latter is catchable.

Comment: yeah, deleted my comment right before you responded. Took a minute to notice you were using SIGTSTP and not SIGSTOP :-)